# Is that "it" redundant?

Tags: sentence-construction, redundancy, repetition

> "What do you anticipate **it** will be the impact of higher tariffs between China and US on your business?"

Is that "it" redundant?

Just like what do you think will be the impact?

Comment: Please can you reference the wider context? At the moment, I beleive that the sentence doesn'e make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The "**it**" is not so much *redundant* as simply **ungrammatical**. It should be removed.

> What do you anticipate will be the impact of higher tariffs between China and US on your business?

It may help to simplify the sentence to understand why. The basic, simplified structure is:

> What ... will be the impact ...?

Comment: Is the "do you anticipate" parenthesis?

Comment: @momsta Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Is the "do you anticipate" interjected remark? or is it inversion? the normal words sequence should be "Do you think what will be the impact of..."

Comment: @momsta I'm sorry, I still don't understand. "Do you think what will be the impact of..." is **not** a "normal word sequence": it is ungrammatical. If you're confused about that you might like to ask a new question about it.

Comment: What, do you think, will be the impact of ... is "do you think" here a interjected  remark?

Comment: @momsta Not really; it's just a question. "What time do you think it is?" "How much do you think it costs?" "Which train should we take?" "What do you think the impact will be?"

Comment: what do you anticipate it will be... Is that grammatical?

Comment: @momsta By itself, yes, because "it" takes the role of the subject. When another subject is given, it replaces "it."

Comment: what do you anticipate it will be the impact of higher tariffs between China and US on your business? Is that "it" redundant?

Comment: **it** will be the impact of higher tariffs between China and US on your business **that** you anticipate what. **it** is formal subject

Comment: what do you think it is? what do you think is? what do you think is that thing?  what do you think it is that thing? so which one is grammatical or ungrammatical?